# How to done Encrypt and Decrypt a string value in android?

Tags: java, android, encryption

Hi I have done this task. But I have to clarify some thing. I did this encryption and decryption like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612460/how-to-decrypting-the-php-encrypted-string-using-android.) Now shat my question is, If I import **android.util.Base64** to my working class is enough for encoding and decoding or I have to include **Base64.java** class. When I remove Base64.java class it also works finely. So what is the purpose of Base64.java class? Can any body clarify me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android.util.Base64 **was added in API version 8 or android 2.2** so it will not be available on the older platforms to support Base 64 in older platforms you need to copy but the source of  [android/util/Base64.java](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and use it.

Comment: So no need to copy this java class to my working project only import is enough to do this task right? Could you tell me am I did in proper way?

Comment: if PHp does encrypt then encode the data then you have to do the reverse first decode and then decrypt the data and viceversa to retrieve the data